# EJB Remote lookup fail in Jboss 7

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I have the following setup:
I'm deploying a ROOT.war file in JBoss 7.1.1 application server.

Inside my ROOT.war file there are 2 things

1. .jar file which contains 1 remote EJB (interface + implementation)
2. Spring petclinic app

In spring petclinic app I have created a controller which sole puprose is to call Remote Ejb's method.
Here is the sources:

```
public class ExampleController {

    public void callRemoteExample() {
        Hashtable<Object, Object> props = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
        props.put(INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        props.put(URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        props.put(PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        Context remoteContext = new InitialContext(props)
        ExampleService service = (ExampleService) remoteContext.lookup("/ROOT/ExampleServiceImpl!com.example.ejbremote.server.ExampleService");
        service.exampleMethod();
    }   
}

@Remote
interface ExampleService {    
    void exampleMethod();
}
```

Jboss starts OK, printing the confirmation that my RemoteEJB is successfylly deployed:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-1) JNDI bindings for session bean named ExampleServiceImpl in deployment unit deployment "ROOT.war" are as follows:

java:global/ROOT/ExampleServiceImpl!com.example.ejbremote.server.ExampleService
java:app/ROOT/ExampleServiceImpl!com.example.ejbremote.server.ExampleService
java:module/ExampleServiceImpl!com.example.ejbremote.server.ExampleService
java:jboss/exported/ROOT/ExampleServiceImpl!com.example.ejbremote.server.ExampleService
java:global/ROOT/ExampleServiceImpl
java:app/ROOT/ExampleServiceImpl
java:module/ExampleServiceImpl
```

But when I actually call the controller's method I get this inside Jboss logs :

```
WARN  [org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) EJB client integration will not be available due to a problem setting up the client context: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEJBClientContext(InitialContextFactory.java:449) [jboss-remote-naming-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:142) [jboss-remote-naming-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web.ExampleController.callRemoteExample(ExampleController.java:270) [classes:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) [org.springframework.web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [org.springframework.web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [org.springframework.web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [org.springframework.web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]


Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getSelector()Lorg/jboss/ejb/client/ContextSelector;
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ejb.RemoteNamingStoreEJBClientHandler.registerEJBClientContextWithSelector(RemoteNamingStoreEJBClientHandler.java:96) [jboss-remote-naming-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ejb.RemoteNamingStoreEJBClientHandler.setupEJBClientContext(RemoteNamingStoreEJBClientHandler.java:63) [jboss-remote-naming-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    ... 48 more
```

P.S. I'm having this issue only on Jboss 7. On a latest Wildfly everything is working as expected.

**UPDATE**

My pom.xml contains this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

What should I put there instead?

Comment: What's the version of your `jboss-ejb-client.jar`?

Comment: Version of jboss-ejb-client.jar is 2.0.1. I also have jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5 in jboss-folder/modules/org/jboss/ejb-client/main. Is that an issue?

Comment: Yes, it is. You've got a clash of jar versions. Mind updating your question with your *pom.xml*?

Comment: what you should put there is the version matching your jboss version, in your case 7.1.1 (which is *quite* old already). Check [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.as/jboss-as-ejb-client-bom/7.1.1.Final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error reported occurs due to a clash of *jar* versions.

The **jboss-ejb-client-1.0.5.Final.jar** of your JBoss AS 7.1.1, present on the folder *jboss_dir/modules/org/jboss/ejb-client/main*, contains a class named `org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext` which does not have the method `EJBClientContext.getSelector()`.

That method was only added on JBoss AS 7.2 (EAP 6.1), as stated [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/229947?tstart=0), which was the precursor version of Wildfly.

On the other hand, the class that references the `EJBClientContext.getSelector()` method, [`RemoteNamingStoreEJBClientHandler`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss/jboss-remote-naming/2.0.1.Final/org/jboss/naming/remote/client/ejb/RemoteNamingStoreEJBClientHandler.java?av=f), was introduced in Wildfly 8 (*jboss-remote-naming-2.0.0.Final.jar*), meaning that's Wildfly specific.

Therefore, the mentioned error is occurring perhaps because you must be declaring the *jboss-remote-naming-2.0.1.Final.jar* as a dependency, on your *pom.xml*, and packaging it with your application.

As @eis mentioned, you should add *jboss-as-ejb-client-bom* dependency to your *pom.xml*. But you must have it as **provided**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As @eis said, you should also add *jboss-as-ejb-client-bom* dependency to your *pom.xml*. But you must have it, as well as your *wildfly-ejb-client-bom* dependency, as **provided**. I've updated my answer with this indications.

Comment: you might want to remove the wildfly dependency from this answer. Since OP is using JBoss 7.1.1, there is no need to have also wildfly libs - in fact I think it might lead to trouble. JBoss one should be enough.

Comment: @eis, you're right. Thank you once again. OP's using JBoss 7.1.1. Wildfly was indeed only used for test purposes. Updating my answer.